# The more comments, the better!

Tags: discussion

There has been a few questions recently which have been closed and then reopened ([How to physically handle hundreds and hundreds of papers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8578/how-to-physically-handle-hundreds-and-hundreds-of-papers/), [How to deal with the frustration of doing PhD at a low-ranked university](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9039/how-to-deal-with-the-frustration-of-doing-phd-at-a-low-ranked-university)). As a moderator, it was particularly difficult to deal with these questions because there were not enough comments explaining the motivations of each "side".

Of course, **it's ok to vote to close a question**, but if you believe this question can be improved, leave a comment explaining why it should be closed and how it could be improved, or upvote a comment left by a previous user. If nobody edits the question, then it's ok to delete  it.

Similarly, **it's ok to vote to reopen a question**, but if the nobody edited the question, please do so, or leave a comment explaining how you believe it could be improved.

Also, **feel free to use up/down-votes**! The more information you provide (in addition to your votes), the better.

Comment: "If nobody edits the question, then it's ok to delete it." - I am sure if I agree with it (unless with additional remark "with no [good] answers.").

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: F'x pointed once to [this answer from Grace Note](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/a/683). Basically, closed questions should be deleted or reopened. If there is a good answer, then the question should be edited to fit with that good answer.

Comment: Editing a question to fit an answer really seems like a solution hunting for a problem.

Answer (score 1):

To add to this: if a discussion is getting long, don't hesitate to bring it here - a meta thread can give folks a lot more room to discuss a closed question, and make it much easier to find past discussions if a similar issue arises in the future.

Just don't forget to provide a link to the discussion in a comment on the question being discussed.